# Letting User Update Password - Parse - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, passwords

I am trying the code below to let users update their password when a uibutton is clicked. However, ever when I enter the current password right, I get the "wrong current password" message. I guess the system does not compare the entered value with the current password right. Without the first if condition, I can update the password. But I want the user to enter current password for security reasons first. May anyone help?

```
@IBAction func updatePasswordBtn(sender: AnyObject) {


    var passwordCheckQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    passwordCheckQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    var objects = passwordCheckQuery.findObjects()


    for object in objects! {


        if currentPassword.text == PFUser.currentUser()!.password {

            if newPassword.text == retypeNewPassword.text {

                var query6 = PFUser.query()

                query6!.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)


                query6!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

                    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    for object6 in objects! {

                        var ob6:PFObject = object6 as! PFObject

                        ob6["password"] = self.newPassword.text

                        ob6.save()

                    }

                }

            }

              else {  println("passwords dont match")
            }

    }

        else {  println("wrong current password")
        }


    }

}
```

I updated my code as below after @Wains comment and it started to work.

```
@IBAction func updatePasswordBtn(sender: AnyObject) {


    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!, password: currentPassword.text) {
        (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {


            var passwordCheckQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
            passwordCheckQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
            var objects = passwordCheckQuery.findObjects()


            for object in objects! {

                if self.newPassword.text == self.retypeNewPassword.text {

                    var query6 = PFUser.query()

                    query6!.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)


                    query6!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

                        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        for object6 in objects! {

                            var ob6:PFObject = object6 as! PFObject

                            ob6["password"] = self.newPassword.text

                            ob6.save()

                            println("successfully updated password")

                        }

                    }

                }

                else {  println("passwords dont match")
                }
            }

        } else {

            println("wrong current password")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: just a note in regards to passwords: dont save them in plain text, hash and salt them! Always! Everybody who is using your app and has set a password is living a dangerous life.

Comment: I am totally with @luk2302 : DO NOT SAVE PASSWORDS AS PLAIN TEXT! That's one of the worst mistakes somebody could make, and if I'd be a user of your app, I wouldn't use it because of that..

Comment: Hello again, actually as i use the parse user table for password storage, arent they hashed automatically? It is sayed that they arent stored in plain text as in the link https://parse.com/questions/are-user-passwords-encrypted-or-hashed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password isn't available to you, so doing `PFUser.currentUser()!.password` isn't going to give you something you can check against. To verify a password you need to log the user in - i.e. take the user name and password they give you and use `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground...`. If you get a valid user back then you can set the `password` and `save`.

Comment: So would it be a problem if I log in a user again that is already logged in?

Comment: In theory, no. If it's the same user who is already logged in it should be fine. If it's a different user then they will become the current user...